# How to set google sheets cell background color to exact shade based on exact decimal value in another cell?

Tags: google-sheets

How can I set the background color of a google sheets cell to an exact fractional value of a color (e.g. 30% of black) based on the value in another cell?

For example, set the background color of A1 to 70% of black if the cell A2 has 0.7 in it.

Conditional formatting gives the option to set specific colors based on a formula, or to set a gradient of colors for a range based on the range's own values, but not really a combination of both of these.

Comment: You need a custom made apps script to do this.

Comment: how can you make a custom apps script? Is it possible to do it through Python (which I am currently using to help manage a spreadsheet through the `gspread` library)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google App Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#creating_a_custom_function) and write the code. For example.

```
function updateCell(e) {
  const ss = e.source
  const currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  const updatedRange = currentSheet.getRange('A1')
  const value = currentSheet.getRange('B1').getValue()
  const color = 255 * (1 - value)
  updatedRange.setBackgroundRGB(color, color, color)
 }

 function onEdit(e){
  updateCell(e)
 }
```

[image]

You can change B1 to another cell position that you want to fill in the value. And change A1 to the position that you want to [change the background color](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundrgbred,-green,-blue). When the sheet has changed the value, it will be called onEdit function every time and go into updateCell function.